# add space between 2 fields in the same row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How can I add some space between the two text fields in the same row? I tried adding margins and paddings, even display flex in the css but nothing seems to work for me.

```
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className="labels">
        <TextField id="filled-basic" label="First Label" variant="filled" />
        <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Second Label" variant="filled" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-cache-7cjow?file=/src/App.js:0-471

Comment: It's working for me. Can you share what's not working?

Comment: For example, ```style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}``` This works as an inline style but not when I add in a separate css file. Could you try on the codesandbox? @CharlesBamford

Comment: What selector are you using for the css ?

Comment: added ```className="firstTextField"```for the first textField @CharlesBamford

Comment: Just checked your codesandbox, it's working fine. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how this is done in [Material ui docs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/).

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: '25ch',
    },
  },
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />
      <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Filled" variant="filled" />
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: I actually already tried this with setting a custom margin and width but it didn't work for me. I am avoiding useStyles and want to use plain css

Comment: If you use material ui I don't think you just can use normal css. What about putting a normal css div wrapper (that's not materisl ui) around each field that you set margin to?

Answer (score 0):

When I put margin inline it works fine:

```
<TextField id="filled-basic" style={{ marginRight: "10px" }} label="First Label" variant="filled" />
```

Comment: I want to avoid inline styles. This works inline but not when I add in a separate css file. Could you try on the codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Grid? As for different screen sizes it will help you.

Here is how to get your desired output:

```
<Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="center">

  <Grid item sm={6} xs={12}>
<TextField
label="Field 1"
name="f1"
type="text"
variant="outlined"
/>
</Grid>

<Grid item sm={6} xs={12}>
 <TextField
label="Field 2"
name="f2"
type="text"
variant="outlined"
/>
</Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

.MuiInputBase-root {
margin: 10px;
}

When I look at the elements in developer tools the classes and ids don't seem to render as one would expect given how they are coded in the component. For example the inputs seem to be wrapped in an element that has the class MuiInputBase-root.
Using that as the selector in the CSS and applying the style to it worked.

Comment: Here's what's actually rendering:  <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiFilledInput-root MuiFilledInput-underline MuiInputBase-formControl"><input aria-invalid="false" id="filled-basic" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiFilledInput-input" value=""></div>